# This question is not a duplicate

Tags: support

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082316/what-is-the-extreme-programming-term-for-programming-without-a-manager#25082316) has been marked a duplicate, despite being nothing at all like the question it is supposed to duplicate.

Comment: Is there a question or request here because I don't see one?

Comment: What do you want support with exactly?

Comment: That question is **terrible**, even the OP admits it.

Comment: Maybe, but it's not a duplicate. I want to have it marked as not a duplicate. I've rerwritten the OP's question to help find his answer -- there is a reason there are process, project-management, and agile tags -- not all questions have to be about code.

Comment: I admit the terribleness of the question, sure. But that's no reason to close it as a duplicate, and especially the duplicate of a *totally different question*. And i said it is terrible because it's not the kind of question that is easy to find, and isn't "code"

Comment: No, not because it isn't "code". It is entirely off-topic. It is a terminology question, nothing to do with what SO is about.

Comment: Your question is like a statement.

Answer (score 7):

By editing the question you've done all that you can do (other than voting to reopen which you don't have the rep for yet).

Editing the question will place it in the reopen review queue where other 3K+ users will see it and if they agree that it's no longer a duplicate they can vote to reopen.

In this case, however, the question isn't suitable for Stack Overflow and if it were reopened it would only be to reclose it.

Comment: where is this question fit for then? I do note it is arguably covered by "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", but that is a stretch.

Comment: @bharal - I'm not sure it has a home anywhere on the SE network. You could try asking in chat - though I don't know which room would be most likely to give you an answer.

Comment: i *did* try asking in chat - no luck, hence the shot at asking it here (where here is, of course, there). Man, when i find the answer, i am totally going to open that champers.

Comment: Possibly [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) (if cleaned up). There are plenty of methodology questions there.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - it would have to be cleaned up **a lot** if it were asked on Programmers. I would not be happy if were asked in it's current state there (speaking as a Programmers mod here).

Comment: There is also a [Project Management SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com/) that this _may_ be on-topic with a lot of clean-up.  Right now, the question as written is awful.